# og meta tags in angular application not working when shared on facebook

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

i am working on the og tags for the first time. Not getting where to place what. i am working on an angular application where i need to share my application link in facebook and it should be loaded with all the tags information i have given.

I have placed the below code in index.html

```
`<meta property="og:title" content="tt">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fjustsomething.co%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F10%2F9.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fjustsomething.co%2F24-amazing-pictures-that-will-make-you-want-to-visit-china%2F&tbnid=CMiYxtKxp1bk6M&vet=12ahUKEwiYzfnPwI_zAhUfj0sFHRymAN0QMygBegUIARCLAQ..i&docid=nhEeg7NaraSfbM&w=733&h=1100&itg=1&q=images&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwiYzfnPwI_zAhUfj0sFHRymAN0QMygBegUIARCLAQ">
<meta property="og:url" content="www.google.com">`
```

and then updating using updateTag() in one of my components in ngOnInit() like

```
`this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:title', content: 'Its vote app'});
this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:image', content: 'https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fjustsomething.co%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F10%2F9.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fjustsomething.co%2F24-amazing-pictures-that-will-make-you-want-to-visit-china%2F&tbnid=CMiYxtKxp1bk6M&vet=12ahUKEwiYzfnPwI_zAhUfj0sFHRymAN0QMygBegUIARCLAQ..i&docid=nhEeg7NaraSfbM&w=733&h=1100&itg=1&q=images&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwiYzfnPwI_zAhUfj0sFHRymAN0QMygBegUIARCLAQ'});
this.meta.updateTag({property: 'og:url', content: 'http://bf79-2401-4900-4bbe-baa4-61db-11ba-fb64-b337.ngrok.io/preview/vote/61483b6635b6d933cff747cc'});`
```

and then what should be done to render the things in my facebook account.

Please do help me. Thank you.

Comment: Facebook gets the source of the page you link to for sharing, they dont run the javascript that is included in the page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me what should be done after placing the meta tags in index.html file so that i get the url, image and title tags dynamically when sharing them on facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need help about this.

Angular is a SPA so it just render the index.html page and update a part of the content when switching between different routes.

From the moment the index.html page is rendered it init metatags you have set in header tag manually. Even when you change route by navigation you won't be able to set other meta tags again.

Even if ...

You found a way to generate them on the serve.
Angular give a way to solve it by enabling SSR (Server Side Rendering) to your application. It will create static version of you application and you will be then able to change dynamically your tags depending on route.

Comment: + to clear the data cached by Facebook, you can use the [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)